# How to find same rows which have same internal in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my Excel I have three columns:

```
Sender  MesageType  Internal
IEKP    DISP.NP     502940
IEKP    DISP.NP     502901
IEKP    DISP.NP     502919
IEKP    DISP.NP     503025
...
```

Number of rows that I have is 10,000. Now, I want to find ONE internal number WHICH have two diffrent Sender (column).

Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: And in your sample data the output would be what?

Comment: @L42 new table with internal numbers and number of diffrent senders (e.g. if sender is IEKP and there is 10 of them with same one internal, count would be 1)

Comment: It is the same thing as I put Filter, and Search form each internal nummber, but this is long way to do

Comment: Have you tried advanced filter which was discussed [here](http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html)? By the way you describe it, AF will do. After that, make a Pivot Table out of it which will give you all unique Internal with its corresponding Sender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pivot table with Internal column as row label, Sender as column label and set the values as COUNT(Internal).
[image]

If you only need Internal and Senders No (number of different senders), you can extract them separately by using formulas.